# Syntax error creating mysql database tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE items (
'itemnumber' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'itemname' varchar(255),
'slot' varchar(255),
'level' varchar(255),
'class' varchar(255),
'white1' varchar(255),
'white2' varchar(255),
'white3' varchar(255),
'purple1' varchar(255),
'purple2' varchar(255),
'purple3' varchar(255),
'id1' varchar(255),
'id2' varchar(255),
'id3' varchar(255),
'green1' varchar(255),
'green2' varchar(255),
'green3' varchar(255),
'icon' varchar(255),
'dateadded' varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY ('itemnumber')
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

returns the following:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''itemnumber' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   'itemname' varchar(255),
>   'slot' va' at line 2

Comment: take time to write a question.

Comment: @Ibu, Take time to write a comment...not "right" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use backticks for the fields:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
`itemnumber` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```